# Trying to list custom categories in custom post type

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have a CPT (products) with custom taxonomy (product-categories) - I am amending archive-products.php to list the categories and I also have a plugin installed to assign an image to the categories.

This is my code in archive-products.php:

```
$taxonomy = 'product-categories';
$tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
?>
<?php
foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
$terms = apply_filters( 'product-categories-images-get-terms', '' );
echo '<li><img src="' . 'if (function_exists('z_taxonomy_image_url')) echo z_taxonomy_image_url();' . '" /><a href="' . esc_attr(get_term_link($tax_term, $taxonomy)) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $tax_term->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $tax_term->name.'</a></li>';
}
```

Except since I put the bit of code inside the image tag, I get the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in /var/sites/e/SITEURL/archive-products.php on line 25

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, you can't just throw a conditional block inside an `echo` statement. If you really need to it has to be a shorthand if-else, but for visual purposes I have put the statement outside the loop:

```
$taxonomy = 'product-categories';
$tax_terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );

foreach($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
    $terms = apply_filters( 'product-categories-images-get-terms', '' ); ?>
    $imgUrl = ( function_exists( 'z_taxonomy_image_url' ) ) ? z_taxonomy_image_url() : '';
    echo '<li><img src="' . $imgUrl . '" /><a href="' . esc_attr( get_term_link( $tax_term, $taxonomy ) ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $tax_term->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $tax_term->name . '</a></li>';
}
```

[Short-hand PHP Examples](http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators).

Comment: I got unexpected $end, removed the extra ?> at the end of the $terms line and now get unexpected t_echo

Comment: Just needed a ; at the end of $imgUrl line, image is still not loading but that is for another topic, this topic is related to the error which is sorted, thanks.